# I like to find correlation between rows?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, cross-correlation

I like to find correlation for rows and compare correlation between rows. But I can find correlation between columns.

```
                A    B    C   D 
1 11132217      2   3    2    2                    
1 111441829     2   2    0    2               
1 12082926      0   2    3    2              
1 150547747     0   0    3    2             
1 151239051     0   2    2    2             
1 161594100     0   3    3    2
```

I used this command but it did not work.

```
sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) cor(data[i,]))
```

Please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

I may be not understanding your question but `cor` can input a dataframe and will do what you want by columns. So why not just transpose your data then do this:

`cor(t(data)`

```
            11132217  111441829   12082926  150547747  151239051  161594100
11132217   1.0000000  0.3333333  0.1324532 -0.5555556  0.3333333  0.4714045
111441829  0.3333333  1.0000000 -0.6622662 -0.7777778 -0.3333333 -0.4714045
12082926   0.1324532 -0.6622662  1.0000000  0.7505683  0.9271726  0.9365858
150547747 -0.5555556 -0.7777778  0.7505683  1.0000000  0.5555556  0.4714045
151239051  0.3333333 -0.3333333  0.9271726  0.5555556  1.0000000  0.9428090
161594100  0.4714045 -0.4714045  0.9365858  0.4714045  0.9428090  1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have performed your code but get NA?

Comment: @star I used your above data. The concept should work. Maybe the data is stored in a funny way. Maybe with factors? Maybe the dataframe isn't the proper type

Comment: @star try posting what `ddput(head(data))` that way we get exactly what you're using